# How to display only first option of attribute - magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I have a certain product with multiselect attribute "year", for the product selected options - 2003,2004,2005.

I use this code - to display a list of options.

```
<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('year')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?>
```

This code returns - 2003,2004,2005.

Is it possible to get only the first option?

I need to display only option "2003".

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<?php $year_values = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('year')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?>
<?php $year = explode(',',$year_values); ?>
<?php echo $year[0]; ?>
```